# How I can cheat an iframe page to be load non in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

In this case I want that an hypothetical javascript code written in example.com return the same result:

*window.self === window.top*

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe id="you-are-not-an-iframe"  src="http://example.com"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to display the contents of the iframe in something like a div rather than a pop-up?

Comment: @user2110309 I quess OP wants to show for example google.com in an iframe.

Comment: Are you looking to [kill the Iframe buster](http://code-cocktail.in/iframe-buster-killer/)

Comment: @Teemu Yes, I want show example.com in an iframe but I don't want  example.com to understand that is loaded by an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser security model forbids you to show a third-party site in a frame, while the site is told that it is running in the top frame.  By the way: Showing remote pages in frames while they don’t want it to happen, is evil IMHO.